# Python relative imports causing pylint errors

Tags: python, python-import, pylint

Here is a *very* simplified version of my projects structure for a program that will execute once then terminate:

```
python-app
├── Dockerfile
└── src
    └── utils
            tools.py
            __init__.py
    └── manage
        └── package_a
            do_something.py
            __init__.py
        __init__.py
    main.py
    __init__.py
```

In main.py I have `from manage.package_a import do_something` , and in do_something.py I have `from utils.tools import a_function`.  I run `python src/main.py` and the program runs has expected.  However in VS Code and when running `pylint` I'm getting the following errors in main.py and do_something.py.

main.py: `Unable to import 'package_a'pylint(import-error)`

do_something.py: `No name 'utils' in module 'tools'pylint(no-name-in-module)`

Am I missing something with relative imports here that is completely bad practice/incorrect? Or is this a pylint issue not recognizing the program will always be run from the main method?

Comment: Have you defined the correct working directory when running in VSCode? Your imports seem fine, but only if the current working directory is correct. Try `print(os.getcwd())` to check, it should be `python-app/src` in your example

Comment: @OferSadan where in VSCode would I do this? settings.json or launch.json?  Would that also remove the error when running pylint from command line?